# How do I resolve this issue with Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm getting this error in my ASP.NET web forms application:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll in the bin is 15.0.1537.0

.NET 4.8 has been installed on the web server which is using IIS Version 8.5.9600.16384

There is also a virtual directory for the website set up on a different server. Do I need to install that dll on the other server too?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms library contains 7 dlls that need to go into your BIN folder.
I recommend that you troubleshoot the issue using MS Process Monitor tool by monitoring access to the *ReportViewer* path and look for the failed access requests.